# VS Problems with Dateadd function using parameters in a query

Tags: visual-studio, parameters

I am creating a report in MS Visual Studio 2008 epxress. The dataset should be limited using parameters. I want the users to have the ability to choose a starting date and then name the number of years into the future they want to see the data.

I created 3 parameters
1. fromdate (Type:Date/Time; visible): This is where they choose a date
2. futureyears (Type: Integer; internal): This is where they should write the number of years into the future
3. todate (Type: Date/Time; internal): This is an internal parameter with the following function as the default value:

=dateadd(DateInterval.Year,Parameters!futureyears.Value,Parameters!fromdate.Value).

fromdate and todate are then used in the query of the dataset to limit the data.

The following error appears when I try to preview this:
"The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter 'todate' contains an error: The expression that references the parameter 'futureyears' does not exist in the parameters collection. Letters in the names of parameters must be use in the correct case"

The thing is: The parameter "futureyears" does exist, when I write the function for the default value of todate, I choose it from the parameters section. so it is there.

I tried to run this report without the futureyears parameter and typed in a random number in the dateadd function. Without the parameter in question, the report runs fine. the problem must be the parameter "futureyears", but I don't know where the problem is. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer myself. Leaving this here in case anyone has a similar problem.

In the parameters folder, the "futureyears" parameter was listed UNDER the "todate" parameter.
All I needed to do for it to work was shift the futureyears parameter ABOVE the todate parameter. Now the report runs fine.